# Pivoting a single field in a table

Tags: sql-server, pivot-table

I have a table of the following structure:

Name
Type
Line
UniqueID
Key
Value

I need to select all the fields except UniqueID field and add a key 'UniqueID' and a Value field with the value of the UniqueID to the result set.

For example if I have three records:

```
Name            Type      Line   UniqueID      Key       Value  
___________________________________________________________________
John Doe        Employee   2     test333       SSN       123-45-2345
John Doe        Employee   3     test333       Address   555 Rodeo Drive
Jane Doe        Visitor    2     test444       SSN       345-67-8907
```

my result set would need to be:

```
Name         Type       Line  Key        Value  
___________________________________________________
John Doe     Employee    2    UniqueID   test333
John Doe     Employee    2    SSN        123-45-2345
John Doe     Emplyee     3    Address    555 Rodeo Drive
Jane Doe     Visitor     2    UniqueID   test444
Jane Doe     Visitor     2    SSN        345-67-8907
```

Do I use pivots? Can anyone point me into the right direction?

Comment: What you're asking to do there is going against the structure of the database model. You're in fact doing *more* harm than good. If this is to be displayed in a report or web application, you'd do better displaying it within the presentation layer like this, rather than trying to manipulate the database structure.

Comment: Thanks for the thought but it was not my choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of an odd request, at least to me.  But anyhow, you can approach it a few ways.  One way is to use cross apply:

```
select
name,
type,
line,
newkey,
newvalue
from 
table1
cross apply
( values
  ('UniqueID',uniqueid),
  ('SSN',Value),
  ('Address',Value)
) c
(newkey,newvalue)
```

[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7019f/9)

Based on your comments, we'll chuck the union all method.

Here is an incredibly ugly and kludgy unpivot, combined with a union (to get the unique ids):

```
select
name,
type,
line,
newkey2,
newvalue
from
(select
name,
type,
line,
[key],
[value]
from table1) t1
unpivot
(
  newvalue for newkey in ([Value])  
 ) u
 unpivot
 (newkey2 for newvalue2 in ([key])) u2
 union all
 select
 name,
 type,
 line,
 'UniqueID',
 Uniqueid
 from
 table1
```

[Unpivot SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/52cd6/1)

Comment: Thanks Andrew. It was not my choice to change the structure that way but it is what it is. Btw, I cannot hardcode the keys since the table is large and there are many different keys

Comment: OK, based on your comments, I dumped the union all (which was the worst choice anyhow), and added a really ugly unpivot.